# C# Swagger response schema is empty when using class from referenced project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm creating a web API, with the response type being from another project, added in the .csproj file. However, the model response schema seems to be empty, even though I can see the correct object being returned when stepping through the code:

[image: Empty model response]

However, if I copy and paste the class that is being returned into my own project (see below), it functions as intended:

```
    public class Info
    {
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<string, string> LatestInfoPerClient { get; set; }
    }
```

The code I'm using to create the endpoint is below (with all the logic removed):

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("get_latest_info")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(Info))]
    public IActionResult GetLatestInfo()
    {
        ...

        return Ok(new Info(result));
    }
```

I'm very confused as to why it functions correctly when the class is from my own project, but not when it's from a referenced project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your action return a typed result:

```csharp
public ActionResult<Info> GetLatestInfo()
{
    ...
    return Ok(new Info(result));
}
```